# how to run puppeteer application in replit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, whatsapp

i want to run whatsapp-web.js module in replit using node.js
I tried the program in the library documentation. namely as follows

```
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require('whatsapp-web.js');

const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
});

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, { small: true });
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.on('message', async msg => {

    const text = msg.body.toLowerCase() || '';

    //check status
    if (text === '!ping') {
        msg.reply('pong');
    }

});

client.initialize();
```

but when run. i get an error like this

```
/home/runner/coba-puppeteer/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241
            reject(new Error([
                   ^

Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
/home/runner/coba-puppeteer/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-982053/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/runner/coba-puppeteer/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:241:20)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (/home/runner/coba-puppeteer/node_modules/whatsapp-web.js/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:231:68)
    at Interface.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Interface.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Interface.close (node:readline:590:8)
    at Socket.onend (node:readline:280:10)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1358:12)
repl process died unexpectedly: exit status 1
```

I've found the problem I may be having is that it doesn't have the libraries required by puppeteer on the system. For example, the error message says "libgobject-2.0.so.0" could not be found. It may be a library that puppeteer needs to run. try installing the required libraries by running the following command in your terminal: `sudo apt-get install libgobject-2.0-0`

however replit cannot use `sudo` command
with error `sudo: The "no new privileges" flag is set, which prevents sudo from running as root.`

has anyone ever managed to run a program using `whatsapp-web.js` in replit?
i am very confused what should i do

the expected output is that **it will print the qrcode from whatsapp on the terminal**